# Mod_rewrite to serve files in just one sub-directory requested in multiple sub-directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a dynamic website. For some reason, I want to serve it as static html files, on a web-host with no database.

The url pattern is:

```
mydomain.com/post-id/article-post-id.html
```

My website has about 800 posts. I've saved all my posts into a single folder on my PC:

`/articles/article-1.html 
 /articles/article-2.html 
 /articles/article-3.html 
 etc.`

It's difficult to create 800 folders and put each file in the corresponding sub-folder. So I have been looking for a code to do the following but ended with nothing that works:

Say the requested url is `mydomain.com/345/article-345.html` and the server serves `/public_html/mydomain.com/articles/article-345.html`

How to accomplish this using `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file in the main directory of the website named ".htaccess". Then, write this in it and save it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/.+\.html$ articles/article-$1.html [NC,L]
```